# TLP Battery charge mode: performance question

Tags: tlp

I've been reading about a good practice to install TLP to avoid battery being constantly overcharged.

I therefore installed the daemon on my Huaweii X Mate Pro. Battery is recognised as far as I can tell.

I set the thresholds as 30% 80%, which according to the doc signal to charge when below 30% and stop when it's 80. My question is, if the battery will be never charged till the max (again another piece of advice I read around), isn't there a risk to have ions working inefficiently over time?

Comment: Good question, although it doesn't seem to belong in askubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was relevant because I was on Ubuntu and I read other TLP related questions before. Any takers?

Comment: Well, "*if the battery will be never charged till the max (again another piece of advice I read around), isn't there a risk to have ions working inefficiently over time?*" doesn't look to me like a TLP-related question, but a [LiPo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium_polymer_battery) battery technology question. 
It is irrelevant that you use TLP to set the thresholds. The same question applies if I use in my Lenovo
`echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold`
to set the threshold.
But if someone answers, I'd be happy to learn about this too!

Comment: Thanks for returning, though I couldn't help but notice your original concern was the question being addressed to the incorrect forum?

Comment: Correct (although I was not "concerned").
You'd probably increase your chances of getting an answer in another forum (I wouldn't know which).
You don't need to mention TLP specifically, as it is irrelevant which method you use to set the thresholds.